# How to get orders in amazon ads reporting api for report spCampaigns?

Tags: node.js, reporting, amazon-advertising-api

I need an orders field when generating a report for Amazon ads report type is sp Campaigns so how to get this orders field?

I am expecting an order count in response like this
{
"date": "2023-05-15",
"cost": 20,
"costPerClick": 0.47,
"unitsSoldClicks1d": 1,
"campaignId": 110041005521111,
"spend": 20,
"clickThroughRate": 0.9287352445194,
"clicks": 440,
"purchases1d": 1,
"sales1d": 49.0,
"impressions": 44,
"campaignName": "xyz"
}